# Finding JDK inside java installation folder on a linux machine

Tags: java

I have been told that in a Linux machine java along with jdk has been installed in /usr/java path.
But when I go to /usr/java/ i could so many files along with folder named bin,JRE. I want to know where is jdk installed here? Is bin folder itself is jdk?

Comment: Write `locate jdk` in your terminal.

Comment: Please share us the `ls` output in the folder.

Comment: Maroun,SOrry its unix solaris machine,can u tell me the respective command?

Comment: ls output is bin,demo,inlclude,jre,copyright,licence,readme.txt,lib,man,sample,src.zip

Answer (score 0):

My `ls` output for openjdk7 looks like this:

```
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  docs     jre  man      THIRD_PARTY_README
bin                 include  lib  src.zip
```

The `jre` folder contains the JRE, the other files are part of the JDK, and not necessary for running Java applications which need only a JRE (e.g. the  `javac` compiler in `bin`).

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type " Which java " this will return JDK installation path

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just installed the JDK under /usr/java. Try run `ls /usr/java/bin`, if `java` and `javac` is in /usr/java/bin, we can conclude that the /usr/java folder IS the JDK folder itself.

Comment: ,yes /usr/java/bin contains java as well javac,But if jdk is installed then there should be folder called jdk right?

Comment: so the /usr/java folder itself should be called jdk in your sense.

Comment: what you can do to reconstruct your desired folder structure is firstly copy /usr/java to a temporary position, create /usr/java folder again, and mv the old /usr/java to /usr/java/jdk. E.g. `mv /usr/java /tmp/old_jdk; mkdir -p /usr/java; mv /tmp/old_jdk /usr/java/jdk`

Comment: got confused!!!I could see jre folder also in/usr/java/ path.Will jdk installs jre also??, i am asking this becoz unix team installed this and we gave only the path /usr/java to install java with jdk

Comment: yeah, there should be a jre folder in a jdk installation. that's just normal :)

Comment: and usually, (at least on linux), JDK is installed under a path like /opt/java/jdk1.7_71 (assuming the jdk being installed is JDK7u71). Since it's pretty common for a machine having more than one version of JDK, it's always good to add the version in the folder name.

Comment: So inside /opt/java/jdk1.7_71 files,folders such as bin,jre should be present right?

Comment: But still I have a doubt ,can we install jdk without folder name like(jdk1.7_71)?

Comment: ..sure, JDK installation is usually simply a folder (some system wide information may also installed, e.g. on Windows, registry entries will be created if you use the Oracle installer, and under linux world, symbolic link under /usr/bin/java and /usr/bin/javac will be setup by package manager or installation script, but that's not necessary for just having a JDK), so you can call it whatever you want.